# Problemas ao plotar gráfico no R com ggplot2

Tags: r, graphics

Preciso plotar um gráfico a partir dos dados de um arquivo .txt, a parte da importação dos dados está okay, no entanto, quando uso a função ggplot, diz que *não foi possível encontrar a função "ggplot"*. Segue abaixo o código que estou tentando utilizar:

```
require("ggdata")
library(haven)
library(readxl)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggalt)


dados <- read.csv(file = "C:/Users/gabri/OneDrive/Documentos/Amostra03.txt", sep = "")

model <- lm(x~y,dados)

ggplot(dados,aes(x=x,y=y)) geom_point()
```

Eu já havia conseguido consertar esse erro, entretanto eu perdi o código por descuido e não me lembro do procedimento que fiz.

Comment: Gabriel, bom dia! Como voce não deu muitos detalhes, o que posso observar que esta errado é a falta do `+` entre o ggplot e o geom_point. O correto seria:  `ggplot(dados,aes(x=x,y=y)) + geom_point()`.

Comment: Sem os `dados` o exemplo não é reprodutível. Não é necessário carregar tantos pacotes e o `lm` é completamente desnecessário. As boas perguntas devem ter dados e o código **mínimo** para reproduzir o problema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gabriel, é sempre importante disponibilizar sua base de dados para aumentar as chances de receber uma resposta.

Observando seu código, o erro está na forma que você escreveu.

Em vez de:

```
ggplot(dados,aes(x=x,y=y)) geom_point()
```

Você deve acrescentar um `+`:

```
ggplot(dados,aes(x=x,y=y)) + geom_point()
```